# Signo de exclamación rojo al crear un nuevo Java Project en eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

Al crear o exportar un Java Project se coloca un signo de exclamación rojo al lado izquierdo del nombre.
¿Qué significa y como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Para arreglar errores del build path, tienes que revisar las propiedades de tu proyecto-> build path. Con mas informaciónes podría ser mas probable que alguien te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Signo de exclamación en eclipse significa que tienes un error en la ruta de construcción ( build path ) de tu projecto.

[Símbolos de eclipse Neon](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Como lo solucionas depende de las razones, para averiguar eso tienes que dirigirte a `Build Path->Configure Build Path` ( configuración de ruta de acceso ) en el menú de contexto de tu proyecto. Posible que te falta una biblioteca de sistema o algo parecido para compilar el proyecto. En todo caso vas a encontrar información mas concreta sobre tu problema en este lugar.